# Ignite topology not stable between nodes through LAN switch

Tags: ignite

I'm setting up a Apache Ignite cluster and have difficulties keeping the topology alive when more than two nodes connect that are connected through a LAN switch.
There are many warnings and problems reported in the log but I wonder what are the correct steps for me to start trying isolate the problem? Ping in both directions works fine, also after some 30s or 1m the connection works but they also lose each other again often. Sometimes the 3rd node trying to connect causes the whole cluster to fail.

```
[20:41:34,761][WARNING][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2][TcpDiscoverySpi] Node is out of topology (probably, due to short-time network problems).
[20:41:34,761][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#28][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.10.161:34361, rmtPort=34361
[20:41:34,762][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDiscoveryManager] Local node SEGMENTED: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=dd44ea86-5302-47a0-b3c0-86acdcf7e771, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.10.162], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, node_2/192.168.10.162:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1524656494760, loc=true, ver=2.3.0#20171028-sha1:8add7fd5, isClient=false]
[20:41:34,764][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#14][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.10.1:55641, rmtPort=55641
[20:41:34,766][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDiscoveryManager] Stopping local node according to configured segmentation policy.
[20:41:34,767][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDiscoveryManager] Node FAILED: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=379eb246-e111-4510-a3f6-09554667d769, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.10.161], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.10.161:47500], discPort=47500, order=2, intOrder=2, lastExchangeTime=1524656073909, loc=false, ver=2.3.0#20171028-sha1:8add7fd5, isClient=false]
[20:41:34,768][INFO][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=6, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=60, heap=2.0GB]
[20:41:34,770][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDiscoveryManager] Node FAILED: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=dd64661b-0679-4a14-9440-d876e5c35bd5, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.0.4, 192.168.10.3], sockAddrs=[/192.168.0.4:47500, /172.17.0.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.10.3:47500], discPort=47500, order=5, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1524656176508, loc=false, ver=2.3.0#20171028-sha1:8add7fd5, isClient=false]
[20:41:34,770][INFO][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=7, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=56, heap=1.0GB]
[20:41:34,771][INFO][Thread-3][GridTcpRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully stopped: TCP binary
[20:41:34,774][INFO][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=7, minorTopVer=0], resVer=null, err=class org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteInterruptedCheckedException: Node is stopping: null]
[20:41:34,774][INFO][Thread-3][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=0], resVer=null, err=class org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteInterruptedCheckedException: Node is stopping: null]
[20:41:34,774][INFO][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Coordinator received all messages, try merge [ver=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0]]
[20:41:34,774][INFO][Thread-3][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], resVer=null, err=class org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteInterruptedCheckedException: Node is stopping: null]
[20:41:34,774][INFO][disco-event-worker-#161][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Merge exchange future [curFut=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], mergedFut=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=379eb246-e111-4510-a3f6-09554667d769, evtNodeClient=false]
[20:41:34,774][INFO][disco-event-worker-#161][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Merge exchange future [curFut=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], mergedFut=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=7, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=dd64661b-0679-4a14-9440-d876e5c35bd5, evtNodeClient=false]
[20:41:34,774][INFO][disco-event-worker-#161][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] finishExchangeOnCoordinator [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=7, minorTopVer=0]]
[20:41:34,787][INFO][Thread-3][GridCacheProcessor] Stopped cache [cacheName=ignite-sys-cache]
[20:41:34,803][INFO][Thread-3][IgniteKernal] 

>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 2.3.0#20171028-sha1:8add7fd5b501b40658096cdde48af9e948aa8150 stopped OK
>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Grid uptime: 00:07:08.412


[root@node_2 apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin]# packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.10.162 port 22: Broken pipe
```

On one of the other nodes something like this is shown after some time:

```
[22:45:54,026][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-6-#127][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=6, bytesRcvd=1578, bytesSent=5266, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-6, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=733187042, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-6-#127]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=4, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=4, sentCnt=4, reserved=true, lastAck=4, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=dd64661b-0679-4a14-9440-d876e5c35bd5, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.0.4, 192.168.10.3], sockAddrs=[/192.168.0.4:47500, /172.17.0.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.10.3:47500], discPort=47500, order=8, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1524656494855, loc=false, ver=2.3.0#20171028-sha1:8add7fd5, isClient=false], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=4, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=4, sentCnt=4, reserved=true, lastAck=4, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=dd64661b-0679-4a14-9440-d876e5c35bd5, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.0.4, 192.168.10.3], sockAddrs=[/192.168.0.4:47500, /172.17.0.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.10.3:47500], discPort=47500, order=8, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1524656494855, loc=false, ver=2.3.0#20171028-sha1:8add7fd5, isClient=false], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/192.168.10.161:47100, rmtAddr=/192.168.10.1:47884, createTime=1524656504308, closeTime=0, bytesSent=5266, bytesRcvd=1578, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1524663359458, lastSndTime=1524656672249, lastRcvTime=1524663359458, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@32244b13, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true]]]
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1233)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2272)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2048)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1717)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[22:45:54,027][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-6-#127][TcpCommunicationSpi] Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Connection reset by peer]
[22:46:41,002][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#119][IgniteKernal]
```

Any idea where I should start looking for the cause of the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the warning

```
[20:41:34,761][WARNING][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2][TcpDiscoverySpi] Node is out of topology (probably, due to short-time network problems).
```

the reason is likely a network issue. Pings may work fine (although I'd check failure rate over a long enough interval, like 10-15 minutes), but try also a long-running TCP connection (maybe via a `netcat` or something).

Another possible reason is high load on the nodes. E.g. if a node goes into a stop-the-world GC and is unable to respond for a long time, it may also be kicked out of the cluster.

To make the cluster more tolerant to short-time network and responsiveness issues, try increasing `IgniteConfiguration.failureDetectionTimeout` setting.

Comment: I still couldn't figure out the cause of my problem. I now have three servers running, two (Sparky Linux based on Debian) connect to each other nicely, while the third (CentOS) doesn't connect. When trying to connect the third it shows: Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to add node to topology because remote node is configured to use loopback address, but local node is not (consider changing 'localAddress' configuration parameter). Why do the remote nodes use 127.0.0.1 as their outgoing IP addresses? I actually set each node to their localAddress in the XML.

Comment: @DonTequila Have you set `localAddress` in both `TcpDiscoverySpi` and `TcpCommunicationSpi`? I guess that might be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for coming back on this. No I haven't in this case. It's quite inconvenient to set the local IP address since this makes configuration system dependent, doesn't it? Any advice here? I noticed though, on a different setup, that discovery and connection is significantly faster when I set the localAddress.

Comment: The connection is faster probably because you have less addresses/interfaces to try. It seems that you can also use `IGNITE_LOCAL_HOST` system property or `IgniteConfiguration.setLocalHost`. With the system property you can avoid having different XML for each node.